# Oracle 11gR2 - Dynamic Registration

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, listener, web-service, tns

Database version: Oracle 11gR2

We want to use DYNAMIC_REGISTRATION_LISTENER parameter with off option.

Our listener.ora file like this:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )



SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1)
      (SID_NAME = oracle)
    )
  )


ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle

DYNAMIC_REGISTRATION_LISTENER = OFF
```

But when we use this parameter, our web service request cannot connect to the database.

```
SQL> SELECT dbms_xdb.gethttpport FROM dual;

GETHTTPPORT
-----------
       3010
```

**Without this parameter:**

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                07-FEB-2021 03:21:59
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 2 min. 51 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=3010))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
```

**With this parameter:**

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                07-FEB-2021 03:21:59
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 2 min. 51 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
```

We need to use this parameter. Web services also need to be connected. How is that possible?

I could not find any clear solution.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you "need" to use this parameter?  I suspect yet another x-y question - that you are asking the wrong question to solve the wrong problem. Alternatively, why can't you just add the necessary entry to the listener configuration?

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=3010))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
    )
  )
```